# Upload multiple files in Laravel

Tags: laravel, multiple-file-upload

I want to upload multiple images at a time, but it doesn't work.

**Blade/View**

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/image/upload') }}" method="POST"enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
    <td><input type="text" name="Fields[0][title]" placeholder="Enter title" class="form-control" /></td>  
    <td><input type="file" name="Fields[0][image]" class="form-control" /></td>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$request->validate([
            'Fields.*.title' => 'required|max:25|min:5',
            'Fields.*.image' => 'required',
        ]);
           if($request->hasFile('image'))
            {
            $file=$request->file('image');
            $file_name=hexdec(uniqid());
            $ext=strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $file_full_name=$file_name.'.'.$ext;
            $upload_path='image/';
            $file_url=$upload_path.$file_full_name;
            $success=$file->move($upload_path,$file_full_name);
        $Fields['image']=$file_url;
       foreach ($request->Fields as $key => $value) {
            images::create($value);
        }
     
         return back()->with('success', 'Image Has Been Saved Successfully.');
}
```

Comment: check this line `if($request->hasFile('image'))`, you don't have any filed called `image`

Comment: What should I write?

Comment: I think you dont need dynamic field here, change `name="Fields[0][image]"` to `name="image"`

Comment: I need dynamic field.

Comment: If you take my answer, you will get array of image and Fields input and you should access throgh "foreach ($request->file('image') as $img) {
            echo $img
        }"

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow below answer:**

**blade file**

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/image/upload') }}" method="POST"enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
    <td><input type="text" name="Fields[]" placeholder="Enter title" class="form-control" multiple /></td>  
    <td><input type="file" name="image[]" class="form-control" multiple /></td>
</form>
```

**comtroller**

```
$request->validate([
    'Fields.*' => 'required|max:25|min:5',
    'image.*' => 'required',
]);
   if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        // dd($request->image) 
foreach ($request->image as $file) {

    dd($file)   
    //get filename with extension
    $filenamewithextension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    //get filename without extension
    $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    //get file extension
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    //filename to store
    $filenametostore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
}

 return back()->with('success', 'Image Has Been Saved Successfully.');
}
```

Comment: I get an error " _Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on array_ "

Comment: Test by dd() then go ahead step by step

Comment: I was copy and paste this.

Comment: copy, past  now and test by dd()

Comment: do not you get any data in dd() function?

Comment: no, Snow this error " Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on array "

Comment: In your controller so may problem. I send you demo only. now take the controller and go ahead as well.

Comment: Now comes in dd(). But shows single file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution helps.(This is for image upload, but you can just delete the image validations)

The first thing is in the form, the field should be like this.

```
<input type="file" name="image_files[]" id="image_files" multiple accept="image/*" />
```

then on your Controller

```
public function uploadFiles(Request $request){
       
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'image_files' => 'required',
            'image_files.*' => 'mimes:gif,png,jpg,jpeg,svg'
        ]);
        
        if($request->hasfile('image_files'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('image_files') as $key => $file)
            {
                $file->move(storage_path('/products/images'),$file->getClientOriginalName());
            }
        }
        
        return "Files uploaded";

    }
```